# What is the source of Umar being more tough on himself than people around him?

Tags: history, source-identification, sahaba

I heard in a lecture that Umar was more tougher on himself than people around him so that is why the people listened to him when he scolded. Also when I was watching the Umar TV series(based on his biography), something similar is told by his wife Atikah to give him comfort when he feels he is too tough on others.
Does someone have a source for these narrations ?